# How to groupBy an iterator without converting it to list in scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Suppose I want to `groupBy` on a iterator, compiler asks to "`value groupBy is not a member of Iterator[Int]`". One way would be to convert iterator to list which I want to avoid. I want to do the `groupBy` such that the input is `Iterator[A]` and output is `Map[B, Iterator[A]]`. Such that the part of the iterator is loaded only when that part of element is accessed and not loading the whole list into memory. I also know the possible set of keys, so I can say whether a particular key exists.

```
def groupBy(iter: Iterator[A], f: fun(A)->B): Map[B, Iterator[A]] = {
    .........
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is, you can convert Iterator to view and then groupBy as,

```
iter.toTraversable.view.groupBy(_.whatever)
```

Comment: How is this different than using a `toList`? Well it's lazy that's true but in the end won't this load all the data into memory anyway? `toTraversable` will make a `Stream`, then when you `groupBy` it still needs to load the whole data anyway, right?

Comment: sorry i thought it only loads when a particular element is accessed. In theory, suppose i have very small num of keys (e.g. 4) and I have a huge list of elements in a iterator. Ideally if we know the keys beforehand, I would only need to access the first occurence of each known key to build the corresponding iterator for each key.  Eg (2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,4,2,3, .......) this part of the list is sufficient  if I know the keys are {1,2,3,4}. After any element is accessed, we repeat similar process to load the next element in each iterator. In your example, its an extreme case and its ok.

Comment: @Mateusz Dymczyk, I saw the document says, groupBy not re-implemented by views, it is forced, but why ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is doable without storing results in memory (and in this case switching to a list would be much easier). `Iterator` implies that you can make only one pass over the whole collection.

For instance let's say you have a sequence `1 2 3 4 5 6` and you want to `groupBy` odd an even numbers:

```
groupBy(it, v => v % 2 == 0)
```

Then you could query the result with either `true` and `false` to get an iterator. The problem should you loop one of those two iterators till the end you couldn't do the same thing for the other one (as you cannot reset an iterator in Scala).

This would be doable should the elements were sorted according to the same rule you're using in `groupBy`.

Comment: I would think that only the part of list be loaded that is necessary to access the most recent accessed element. Only this part will be in memory.

Comment: @Arun but what good does the most recently accessed element give you? As in my example if you have `1 2 3 4 5 6` if you `groupBy` and want to get all the odd elements you need to iterate over the whole thing, even through the even numbers. If you only load the most recent element you will eventually load an even number and your iterator will return `false` even though there might be odd numbers ahead.

Comment: sorry i thought it only loads when a particular element is accessed. In theory, suppose i have very small num of keys (e.g. 4) and I have a huge list of elements in a iterator. Ideally if we know the keys beforehand, I would only need to access the first occurence of each known key to build the corresponding iterator for each key. Eg (2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,4,2,3, .......) this part of the list is sufficient if I know the keys are {1,2,3,4}. After any element is accessed, we repeat similar process to load the next element in each iterator. In your example, its an extreme case and its ok

Comment: @Arun the only way you can do that is with some kind of a buffor,  because if you will first take the value for `3` and then want to access all the values for `2` you need to have them in memory as iterators cannot go back. In the worst case scenario you'd have to store the whole collection in memory.

Answer (score 0):

As said in other responses, the only way to achieve a *lazy* groupBy on Iterator is to internally buffer elements. The worst case for the memory will be in `O(n)`. If you know in advance that the keys are well distributed in your iterator, the buffer can be a viable solution.

The solution is relatively complex, but a good start are some methods from the [`Iterator`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/Iterator.scala) trait in the Scala source code:

- The [`partition`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/Iterator.scala#L553) method that uses both the `buffered` method to keep the head value in memory, and two internal queues (lookahead) for each of the produced iterators.
- The [`span`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/Iterator.scala#L580) method with also the `buffered` method and this time a unique queue for the leading iterator.
- The [`duplicate`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/Iterator.scala#L1070) method. Perhaps less interesting, but we can again observe another use of a queue to store the gap between the two produced iterators.

In the groupBy case, we will have a variable number of produced iterators instead of two in the above examples. If requested, I can try to write this method.

Note that you have to know the list of keys in advance. Otherwise, you will need to traverse (and buffer) the entire iterator to collect the different keys to build your Map.