# Scala Iterator vs Other collections?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, large-data, large-files

I am sifting through a large data set, parsing and grouping based on same keys. But to use groupBy function I need to convert my iterator to an `Array`. Why is groupBy not present in `Iterator`? I understand how an iterator works and that an iterator can iterate through the elements only once. But when you provide methods like `map`, `filter`, `foreach` etc on Iterator why not provide `groupBy` as well?
Is there any specific reason for this? Because converting an iterator to an Array takes more time when you work with large data.

Comment: You don't have to convert to `Array`. You might do `.toStream` instead. Then it has a `groupBy` and it's still lazy. That is, it's lazy until you invoke the `groupBy`, which will force evaluation, which makes sense because you can't know if any particular group is complete unless you inspect the entire original collection, which would exhaust an iterator.

Comment: @jwvh : toStream() does not make any difference. It has the same performance as with array.

Comment: Yes and no. `itr.toStream` is much faster than `itr.toArray` (try it on an infinite `Iterator`) but, as I indicated previously, `itr.toStream.groupBy()` won't be better than `itr.toArray.groupBy()`, which wouldn't be any better than `itr.groupBy()` (if there were such a thing), because they all load the entire iterator contents into memory.

Comment: @jwvh : Why do you say that iter.toStream is much fater thatn itr.toArray ?

Comment: Because `.toArray` has to realize every element of the iterator and load it all into memory. `.toStream` doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

One approach to avoid loading the entire dataset into an Array or List from an Iterator is to use `foldLeft` to assemble the aggregated `Map`.  Below is an example of computing the sum of values by key via `foldLeft` from an Iterator:

```
val it = Iterator(("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("b", 3), ("b", 4), ("c", 5))

it.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int]){ case (m, (k, v)) =>
  m + (k -> (m.getOrElse(k, 0) + v))
}
// res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 3, b -> 7, c -> 5)
```

Re: problem with `groupBy` on an Iterator, here's a relevant [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29427059/how-to-groupby-an-iterator-without-converting-it-to-list-in-scala) and [Scala-lang link](https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/6735).